# Should nsfetchedresultscontroller be set to nil when a user clicks on a different tab in tabbed interface?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am writing an app with tabbed interface and few uitableviews. I am loading the nsfetchedresultscontroller in viewdidload and when the user switches from one tab to another i don not set nsfetchedresultscontroller to nil so that when the user comes back the data will still be loaded.  Is this a good practice?  If i would have to reload the data every time it would be somewhat slow because i load a lot of data in the tableview.  Otherwise i would have to setup some kind of paging mechanism for the tableviews.

Thanks!